# Problems with saving unicode to sqlite

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, sqlite

I am currently doing a project which consists of reading a log file from a SMTP server, and extracting meaningful information about every email that passes by. I have a table that has some columns that will be later on relevant for searching; Spam Score, From Domain, To Domain, time stamps, subject, etc.
Everything works fine until I encounter some non ASCII character, which is usually on the subject field (as expected).

I've tried to decode the str to iso-8859-1 (which is the file's encoding) and save it, and I've also tried to encode it back to UTF-8, and to be honest, I'm a bit lost here. I've heard that working with unicode in python 2.7 is a nightmare, but I've never experienced it up until now.

Anyway, let me explain. This is how I'm extracting the subject:

```
if 'subject' in realInfo: 
emailDict[keywrd].setSubject(realInfo[realInfo.index('subject') + 
len('subject') + 1:].decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

emailDict is a dictionary containing all the emails that are being processed.

And this is how I'm inserting everything into the database:

```
    info = (e.getID(), str(e.getSpamScore()), str(e.getMCPScore()), " ".join(e.getFrom()), " ".join(e.getTo()), e.getStatus(), e.getTimestamp(), e.getSubject(), dumps(e))
    print repr(e.getSubject())  # DEBUG
    print type(e.getSubject())  # DEBUG
    self.conn.cursor().execute(u"INSERT INTO emails (emailID, SpamScore, MCPScore, FromDomain, ToDomain, status, timestamp, subject, object)"
                      " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", info)
    self.conn.commit()
```

I've added 2 print statements to help me understand where the problem is.

'e' is an Email Object that serves as a blueprint for every email. It contains information, previously obtained by an interpreter. After that, I am saving the most important information on columns that, as said before, will be used for searching (the 'object' column is an email object, using pickle here). But as soon as special characters appear, an exception is raised:

```
u'VPXL \xffM-^W no more compromises. Better size, better life. \n'
<type 'unicode'>
Exception in thread Thread-25:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/ProjMail/projMail_lib.py", line 174, in refresher
self.interpreter.start()
File "/ProjMail/projMail_lib.py", line 213, in start
c.save(self.emailTracker)
File "/ProjMail/projMail_lib.py", line 56, in save
self.saveEmails()
File "/ProjMail/projMail_lib.py", line 62, in saveEmails
else: self.add(key) # If it's new
File "/ProjMail/projMail_lib.py", line 82, in add
" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", info)

ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a 
text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). 
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to 
Unicode strings.
```

From what I see, it IS unicode, so I cannot understand why sqlite is complaining.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not inserting the subject itself into the database, it's inserting the pickled `Email` instance.

```
>>> subject = u'VPXL \xffM-^W no more compromises. Better size, better life. \n'
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = conn.cursor()                            
>>> c.execute("""CREATE TABLE foo (bar text, baz text)""")                                   
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fab5cf280a0>
>>> c.execute("""INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?)""", (subject, 'random text'))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fab5cf280a0>

>>> class Email(object):pass
... 
>>> e = Email()
>>> e.subject = subject
>>> c.execute("""INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?)""", (subject, pickle.dumps(e)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

Picking the `Email` instance creates a bytestring with mixed encodings internally, triggering the exception (even picking only `subject` would do this).

To prevent the exception you could change the connection's text_factory attribute to `str`:

```
>>> conn.text_factory = str
>>> c.execute(stmt2, (subject, pickle.dumps(e)))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fab5b3343b0>
```

If you would prefer to keep using the default `unicode` `text_factory`, you could store the pickled class in a `blob` column, wrapped in a `buffer` instance.

```
>>> conn.text_factory = unicode
>>> c.execute("""CREATE TABLE foo2 (bar text, baz blob)""")
>>> c.execute("""INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?)""", (subject, buffer(pickle.dumps(e))))                       
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fab5b3343b0>
```

The pickled instance is restored on retrieval:

```
>>> c.execute("""SELECT bar, baz FROM foo2""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fab5b3343b0>
>>> res = c.fetchone()
>>> res
(u'VPXL \xffM-^W no more compromises. Better size, better life. \n', <read-write buffer ptr 0x7fab5e9706c8, size 167 at 0x7fab5e970688>)
>>> pickle.loads(res[1])
<__main__.Email object at 0x7fab5b333ad0>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, and it worked! Thanks a lot!